# Jquery .html, Firefox encodes qoutes in attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a hotfix app which generates HTML slides. The modules are built in Jquery with the background as inline CSS (the best solution i could come up with since they are unique per instance).

The problem is that firefox converts the quotes in the style attribute into:

```
<div style="background-image: url(&quot;bigspace-template.jpg&quot;);"
class="nuiOpenspace t1 skin1">
```

The webkit browsers have no issues with this.

They only way i have been able to get the background attribute is by:

```
// Build function, shortened
openspace.build = function(){
// ...
var bgstr = 'background-image: url('+ this.val_image + ')';
$o = $('<div class="nuiOpenspace"></div>').attr('style', bgstr);
// ...
}
```

This is then output appended to the document:

```
function Sandbox(){
    var $sandbox = $("#sandbox");
    
    this.fill = function(o) {
        $sandbox.empty();
        $sandbox.append(o);
    };
    // ...      
}
```

I then get the HTML from the dom, convert to string and then output it in a textarea:

```
function Source(){
    
    this.print = function(o, c_val){
    
        //var parsed_html = this.parse(o, c_val);
        //var pretty_html = "";         
        //pretty_html = style_html( parsed_html );

        //console.info(x.replaceAll('&qout;', 'x'));            
        
        $code.text( style_html($("#sandbox").html()) );
    };
}

var source = new Source();
```

I´ve tried search and replace but firefox keeps changing to / adding ". Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried using single qoutes? `'`. Or, you could just put it in a temporary element, and get the `.text()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, the `&quot;` is a `"`, so you have `"` inside something that is in between its own `"`. That can never work like this I think.

If you would've changed the origional code (the one that didn't work in firefox) to valid code (using either escapes or a combination of `'` and `"` instead of "nested" `"`), wouldn't you be closer to a solution?